# Could not find devise mapping for path "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm putting a form on the landing page of my app that will let the user login. The problem is that devise does not have a route for "/". I've tried adding the route with the following:

```
devise_for :pages, :controllers => {:home => 'home'}
```

but I just don't have it quite right. Does anyone have any hints on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the devise github README:

After signing in a user, confirming the account or updating the password, Devise will look for a scoped root path to redirect. Example: For a :user resource, it will use user_root_path if it exists, otherwise default root_path will be used. This means that you need to set the root inside your routes:

```
root :to => "home"
```

You can also overwrite after_sign_in_path_for and after_sign_out_path_for to customize your redirect hooks.

Answer (score 7):

Add the root route to your devise block like so:

```
devise_scope :users do
  root :to => "users#new"
end
```